# Sbt outjava.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Tags: sbt

Searching on the internet the only relevant information found is at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2156#issuecomment-140359444; however I don't see the solution for this problem.

The project is freshly setup with Java 1.8.0_131-b11 64bits, Scala 2.11.11, sbt 0.13.15. Basically there is no plugins just a standard sbt layout project. Although frequency of such errors is not very high, it's inconvenience as not sure how to fix that.

Is there any solution for this issue? Thanks

```
/path/to/target/streams/$global/ivySbt/$global/streams/outjava.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:10)
    at sbt.IO$.touch(IO.scala:210)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.make(Streams.scala:129)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.text(Streams.scala:113)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log(Streams.scala:124)
    at sbt.std.TaskStreams$class.log(Streams.scala:56)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log$lzycompute(Streams.scala:102)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log(Streams.scala:102)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$ivySbt0$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1338)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$ivySbt0$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1337)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:35)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$1.apply$mcZ$sp(IO.scala:210)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$1.apply(IO.scala:210)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$1.apply(IO.scala:210)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:10)
    at sbt.IO$.touch(IO.scala:210)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.make(Streams.scala:129)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.text(Streams.scala:113)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log(Streams.scala:124)
    at sbt.std.TaskStreams$class.log(Streams.scala:56)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log$lzycompute(Streams.scala:102)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log(Streams.scala:102)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$ivySbt0$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1338)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$ivySbt0$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1337)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:35)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You should post your project configuration so that people can try to reproduce and solve the problem